# How to center two buttons next to each other but center of the screen?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

[image]

This is definitely such a basic question but I'm trying to do this in Ionic. I've been trying

```
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
```

so many things but it's not working, help?

**UPDATE:** So I've tried one of the solutions and this is my CSS, but it still doesn't work, its center, but all the way at the top

```
.square{
    width: 25vw;
    height: 8vw;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container"
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button class="button button-outline square button-calm">
            Male
        </button>
        <button class="button button-outline square button-royal">
            Female
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your complete (or at least relevant) code? The HTML, more of the CSS, etc.

Comment: made an update still not working

Comment: Check the end of the first line of your HTML, you missed a `>`. Is this what's causing your problem, or did you just miss-type it when bringing your code over to StackOverflow? `<div class="container"` should be `<div class="container">`

Comment: @Huang Chen if it's stuck all the way at the top, it probably means the `body` is short. Use a height value as you will see in my example. Verify its height by inspecting the code in Dev Tools. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWVxJr

Comment: @Xetnus did not fix it

Comment: @alanbuchanan added the height to the body of 100vh still not working

Answer (score 5):

You can use flexbox to achieve this. Firstly wrap the buttons within a container:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <button class="male">Male</button>
    <button class="female">Female</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, in the CSS, apply vertical and horizontal centring to the children of the container:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akZjBK)**

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with iconic framework. But I think following suggestions might work, give it a try:
1) You can try `<center>` tag
2) or you can try `left:50%;` (which is setting the left margin)

Answer (score -2):

I've decided to do

```
.square{
    width: 25vw;
    height: 10vw;
}

.container {
    padding-top: 35vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%
}
```

not sure how good of a convention this is, but it seemed to center it decently on different devices

Comment: You should choose Alan Buchanan's answer with your modifications in comments.